# How could I product summary tags for a massive table of keywords, e.g. a-z aren't enough, need ab - ac etc?

Tags: mysql

I have a massive table of keywords, a keyword appears with a foreign key e.g.

```
key=2 word=download
key=3 word=download
key=4 word=game
```

At the moment I have another field called letter index so for the above example I'd have d,d,g

I then group all the keywords and all the keywords with a specific letter index on each page.

e.g.
page a, would should audio(10) to aztec(23)

So thats ten audio records found. etc

26 pages isn't enough. a-z

I need a way to create a new index field, with 3 letters in it. e.g. 000 to ccc etc

Just looking for some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that you want your groups not smaller than some reasonable `N`. We'll build the smallest groups larger than `N`. We also assume that every group at least starts with the same letter. Later we can unite groups that are too small if we want.

Here's a simplified pseudocode:

```
result = {} # a mapping: prefix -> size of group by that prefix
source = iterator(sorted(keyword_list)) 
while source.hasNext():
  # try to determine size of a group that start with prefix
  prefix = source.next() # (see note)
  size = 1
  while size < N and prefix.length > 0:
    while source.hasNext() and prefix.length > 0:
       # count keywords that start with current prefix
       keyword = source.next()
       if keyword.startsWith(prefix):
         size += 1
       else:
         # shorten prefix; all previous matches match the shorter prefix, too
         prefix = removeLastLetterFrom(prefix) # 'aba' -> 'ab'
         source.stepBack() # we want the unmatched keyword on next iteration
  result[prefix] = size
```

Note: we assume that the keyword we first encounter is long enough as a prefix. This may not always be true; if you have very short keywords like 'a' or 'que', you'll need to skip the keywords that a too short, incrementing `size`. This will add a few corner cases.

Hope this helps.